# How to run animation every time onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I want an animation that runs on every click.

However, it runs only the first time and not after the second click.

Is there a way?

```
  const inputEl = useRef();
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    inputEl.current.style.animation = "0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 testKeyword";
  };
```

```
return(
   <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
   <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
);
```

```
@keyframes testKeyword {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: To re-render, you can change the state onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 different solutions depending on your needs:

Solution 1: using `useRef`

js file

```
const inputEl = useRef();

const handleButtonClick = () => {
    inputEl.current.style.animation = "0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 testKeyword";
}

const handleAnimationEnd = () => {
    inputEl.current.style.animation = "none";
}
```

```
<input ref={inputEl} onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd} type="text"/>

<button onClick={handleButtonClick} >Focus the input</button>
```

css file:

```
@keyframes testKeyword {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Solution 2: using `useState`

js file:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

<input type="text" class={clicked === true ? "animate" : null} onAnimationEnd={() => setClicked(false)}/>

<button onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>Focus the input</button>
```

css file:

```
.animate {
  animation: 0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 testKeyword;
}

@keyframes testKeyword {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help! I am using a `class` that contains the animation and then I am adding it on button click, then after `700ms` I am removing this class using `setTimeout`

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    const inpEl = document.querySelector(".Demo-input");
    inpEl.classList.add("Demo-animate");
    setTimeout(() => {
      inpEl.classList.remove("Demo-animate");
    }, 700);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Demo">
        <input className="Demo-input" type="text" />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Click Me </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.Demo-animate {
  animation: 0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 testKeyword;
}

@keyframes testKeyword {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the animation style property of the element once and after the animation has completed 100%, it won't start again. What you can do is add a class to the element which changes the style of the element and remove it after some time interval.

```js
const onButtonClick = () => {
    const element = document.querySelector("input");
    element.classList.add("fade");
    setTimeout(() => {
      element.classList.remove("fade");
    }, 200);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
```

The CSS for the same would look something like this

```css
.fade {
  animation: 0.7s ease-in-out 0s 1 testKeyword;opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes testKeyword {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**Note:**
This implementation uses setTimeout which is an asynchronous API. It may happen at some point in time when the stack is not empty and the callback to remove the *fade* class is waiting in the task queue, then the code will freeze until the task is cleared. This is a rare case but it is important to know about it.
You can refer to this video on eventloop (What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU) on youtube to understand this better. Here is the link https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=769